# Scrollpositionrestoration setting is not working in ionic 4 angular 8

Tags: ionic4, angular8

I changed routing module to keep scroll top on loading page in ionic 4 angular 8
but It is not working and keeping the scrolled position.

inserted code is underline.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
 {
 preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules, // default
 enableTracing: false,
 onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
 scrollPositionRestoration: 'top', // inserted paramenter
})
```